# Set a dynamic filter value

Tags: views

I want to construct a view with following constraints:

- Show entries from the content-type XY **AND** it is authored by the currently logged in user

**OR**

- Show entries from the content-type XY **AND** the first field/column corresponds to the currently logged in user

**OR**

- Show entries from the content-type XY **AND** the second field/column corresponds to the currently logged in user

I do know about contextual filters, but I cannot use them when I want to introduce OR with filter groups as they are applied on the entire view.

Is it possible to input a dynamic value instead of a hardcoded value? - in my case the currently logged in user:
[image]

Comment: You can change its value programmatically using `hook_views_pre_view` [as shown here](https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2015-04-27/change-filter-value-in-views#comment-12407408)